# How to see information about hard drives in Windows Server 2003 using Dell PERC 6/i Integrated RAID Controller

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell, dell-perc

I just found out one of my servers are reporting hard drive error but I'm having problems extracting the information I want.

I've downloaded Acronis Drive Monitor so I could see hard drive health and serial numbers, but it only shows the raid controller and not the drives.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using a Dell PERC controller, you should also use the appropriate tool for managing it - Dell provides the [OpenManage Server Administrator Storage Management](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/5.1/en/omss_ug/html/index.html) for exactly this purpose. It will help you identify and replace the failed disk of your array.

Comment: Of course it's not installed, but I trust you it's the right way to go, thanks.